# Floats appearing over an element's background

Tags: html, css, css-float

Look at [this](http://jsbin.com/izedip/2/edit) JSBin example. If I float an element, it will move the text surrounding it (like it should) but it will still appear over an element's background, which I don't want. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `overflow:hidden` to the element whose background is extending behind the float. In your case this would be your `#hello` div.

```
#hello {
 background-color: #ffc; 
 padding: 1em;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

### http://jsbin.com/izedip/3/edit#preview